# On the Coincidence of Two Events

Tags: linear-algebra

In the 2014 TV show Silicon Valley, billionaire Peter Gregory makes the following statement:

> The cicadas of Myanmar emerge every 13 years while the Brazilian
> cicadas emerge after every 17. Next year, they will hatch
> simultaneously for the first time in 221 years.

I wondered whether this (the simultaneous hatching) was actually possible, so I started working on it. This is how I handled the problem:

1. For Myanmar, let `M` be the year of first hatching. Thus, the cicadas will emerge in the series of years expressed by `M+13`.
2. For Brazil, let `B` be the year of first hatching. Thus, the cicadas will emerge in the series of years expressed by `B+17`.

Simultaneous hatching implies that `M+13` equates to `B+17`. I wrote a computer program to check for such instances in the next `1,000,000` years but none showed up.

Am I calculating this incorrectly, or was the TV show just inaccurate in this case?

Comment: Use your computer program to calculate the product $13\times 17$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I don't get it

Comment: If they hatch simulataneously during a certain year, they will hatch again simultaneously 221 years later (sorry, had to use my calculator).

Comment: In the computer age , it is apparently too difficult to calculate $13\cdot 17$ by hand :) This has nothing to do with coincidences. We have two periodical occurences and it is trivial that the period length for the occurence of both simultaneously is the least common multiplier of the two period lengths.

Comment: TV shows are apparently still the best way to earn (almost) infinite money without a significant effort. Too bad that I am not such a moderator and do not have the paradise on earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your program, it's hard to know specifically where you went wrong (although I have a few guesses), but here's how it works:

- Let's mark the year the two types of cicada hatched simultaneously as year $0$.
- Then the Myanmar cicadas will hatch in the years $13, 26, 39, 52, \ldots$.
- And the Brazil cicadas will hatch in the years $17, 34, 51, 68, \ldots$.

So the next time they will hatch in the same year is going to be the next time that $13N = 17M$ for some $N, M$. (For example, $N = 3$ corresponds to the year 39, but there's no whole number $M$ that lets $17M = 39$ so that's no good.)

We know that 13 and 17 are prime, and so if $17M$ is a multiple of 13 then that means $M$ must be a multiple of 13, and similarly if $13N$ is a multiple of 17 then $N$ is a multiple of 17. In fact, the smallest positive solution we have is when $N = 17, M = 13$ because it's very clear that $13 \times 17 = 17 \times 13 = 221$, so the next time the years line up is 221 years later.

Comment: Thank you for the explainer! +1